# Prevent Line Break After @Html.LabelFor In ASP.NET MVC 4 Using Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Here is my code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </li>
    </ol>
 </fieldset>
}
```

From the code above, the label and the textbox are on separate lines. I want to combine them to be on the same line so I can have something like...

```
@Html.LablFor(m => m.FirstName): @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

Should end up looking like FirstName: ***_*__*_*__*_***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can achieve this with css, but we'll need to see your html.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your CSS because `<label>` and `<input>` are both inline elements. The only reason they would be appearing on separate lines would be if your CSS are treating them as block elements or if they cannot fit on the same line of content.

Demo in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tSFtJ/

Comment: I'm gonna' check that, I didn't even think of it. Must be MS's default CSS that does that. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Here is what I did to make this work for me (snippet of code below).
View Model

```
<!-- language: c# -->
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "LabelEmail", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.GeneralResource))]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

View.cshtml

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { style="display:inline;"})
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
</div>
```

The important bit is the:
new { style="display:inline;"}
in the LabelFor(..).
Works like a charm.