# html items not appearing on same line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, visual-studio

In the html below I'm having trouble getting the label and it's corresponding radio button to appear on the same line, what's the correct way to do this?

thanks

```
<div class="display-field">
            @foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(items.titles)))
            {
                    <div class="display-field">
                            @Html.Label(value.ToString())
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.title, value)
                    </div>
            }
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio buttons and label to display in same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306117/radio-buttons-and-label-to-display-in-same-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the label's CSS style to `inline-block`.

```
@Html.Label(value.ToString(), new { style = "display: inline-block" })
```

Without seeing the CSS for your page, the label element that is produced from your call to `@Html.Label()` is likely set to block level (`display: block`).  Block level elements stack on top of each other and inline/inline-block level elements don't.

Please keep in mind that you should set the `display` value in your CSS and not by preference in the `htmlAttributes` value of your helper.  You would do this by putting this (or something better targeted in your CSS file):

```
label { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using LabelFor instead of Label

```
@Html.LabelFor
```

For more details, here is a tutorial for labels 
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-label-labelfor

Comment: thanks for the link, but it just yields the same thing where the value for title is on one line and the radio button on the next

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the css then, because @Html labels are supposed to appear in the same line.
Try the following articles, hope they can help 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437621/label-and-text-box-on-the-same-line-using-css

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144845/prevent-line-break-after-html-labelfor-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-razor

Comment: You shouldn't have to use a different helper to generate the HTML, just to get a label to appear inline-block.  Use CSS styling instead.